# C-style arbitrary precision calculator pass variable

Tags: bash

I have a problem with calc.

I need to pass some variables to calc from command line or script; these variables are complex number like `a=2+5i`, `b=1-i`.

My objective is include this procedure in a bash script; i've test something like

```
$ calc(){ awk "BEGIN { print "$*" }"  ;}
$ a=7; b=3;
$ calc $a/$b
2.33333
```

but unfortunately, if either a or b are complex my code fails, giving wrong and not plausible results.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: AWK has no built-in support for complex numbers. You'd be better off using a language such as python to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change awk in the `calc` function to its python equivalent:

```
$ calc () { python -c "print ($*)"; }
$ calc 2 + 3
5
$ calc "(3 + 4j) * 2"
(6+8j)
$ calc "(2 + 5j) / (1 - 2j)"
(-1.6+1.8j)
```

If you want/need to use `i` instead of `j`, change the function to
`calc () { python -c "print (${*//[Ii]/j})"; }`